# subprocess popen + curl + binary data

Tags: python, curl, popen

The following statement works as expected:

```
os.system("curl --data-binary \@"+input_file_path+" -o "+ file_name +" localhost:30")
```

But when trying it with `subprocess.popen`:

```
Popen(['curl','--data-binary','\@'+input_file_path, '-o', file_name,'localhost:30'], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

Curl seems to hang up(logs into endless loop), like if the input file is not passed to it(which is mandatory for localhost:30 to function properly)...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the original string in `subprocess.Popen` with the additional keyword argument to `Popen` of `shell=True`:

```
subprocess.Popen("curl --data-binary \@"+input_file_path+" -o "+ file_name +" localhost:30",
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    shell=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

how about [using a library](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/) instead of calling system's curl?

Comment: Because sometimes you do not want to wait for a response or wait at all, just fork-detach and forget. Like when logging.

Comment: Another good http python library is '[requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)' library